# Generate an email as soon as new value is added to a database?

Tags: php, sql

I have been struggling hard to solve this problem if any one here could help me out !

i have created a web form which takes data from a user and update it to the database which has fields like ( unique id, email, time of reg, visitor count)

What i want is to auto generate a mail as soon as a new user register to the database. The mail should go to the email id of the new registered user with the uniqie id and a small content .. !

Comment: If user is correctly saved to db, just [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) whatever to him.

Comment: I have created the database and form that is able to update the database when user click on submit. I could not do the mailing part...

Comment: This is easy. Call the email function in the same condition where you insert the new user in the db.

Answer (score 1):

Create a trigger on the database that generates an email on insert.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy and simple

```
mail('name1@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
```

for more details you can follow below link

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the script that you use to register the user and as soon as you have stored the entry in the database, send him an email with php's mail function

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($newuser)
{
mail("admin@myaddress.com", "New User Notification", "User $newuser joined on $datejoined."); }
```

Very simple, but works.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are inserting the data in your dbase, get the insert I'd or rows affected which is returned by the query.  Then you can use a condition like
     if (isset($insertid)){ do something, like email }

Look up insert_id() or affected_rows().